# Error in inla.call.builtin() : INLA installation error; no such file

Tags: r, geospatial, r-inla

I have recently updated INLA using the inla.update on my machine. Now everytime I try to run a function from the package, such as inla.mesh.2d I obtain the following error:
*Error in inla.call.builtin() : INLA installation error; no such file*
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling INLA package both in its testing and stable version but it still won't work.
I will paste below the output from sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] it_IT.UTF-8/it_IT.UTF-8/it_IT.UTF-8/C/it_IT.UTF-8/it_IT.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] INLA_22.01.16 sp_1.4-5      foreach_1.5.1 Matrix_1.3-4 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3   tools_4.0.3      tinytex_0.32     splines_4.0.3    codetools_0.2-18 grid_4.0.3      
[7] iterators_1.0.13 xfun_0.23        lattice_0.20-44
```

Thank You!

Comment: Try upgrading R to the newest version for your Mac.  The [news page](https://www.r-inla.org/news#h.acsz4qx97vdq) says, "Native build for R-4.1 and Mac M1 processor, included ported PARDISO library."  Even thought it doesn't necessarily mean the old R versions stop working, it's worth a shot.

Comment: I tried updating it to both the stable and testing version but that was not working. I eventually deleted both R and Rstudio and re-installed both and INLA and now it seems to be working, thanks anyways!

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I've tried installing an older version with

    remotes::install_version("INLA", version="22.05.03",repos=c(getOption("repos"),INLA="https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/testing"), dep=TRUE)

but i'm still getting this error message after loading the pkg and calling inla()

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting may be resolved if you update your R to its latest version so INLA requirements are met. Restart after updating R.

If this does not resolve the problem, installing directly from the R interface (vs RStudio) might fix the problem. This link explains how it is done and might be helpful if the first solution did not help.

https://groups.google.com/g/r-inla-discussion-group/c/f3LAE2VHZQw

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).